# Extracting matrices from list of list sub-elements keeping the list/sub-list indices for the matrix

Tags: r, list, lapply, sapply

New to r and was hoping to find an elegant way of solving what seems like a simple problem.  The context of the problem is as follows: I am running regressions for a set of companies at rolling periods of time.  I am storing the summary of each regression in a list of lists.  So, for example:

`results[[i]][[t]] = summary(lm(y~x))`, where `y` and `x` are the associated vectors for company `i` at time `t`. I would like to extract matrices like `sigma` from `results` such that:

```
sigma[i,t] = results [[i]] [[t]]$sigma
```

Clearly I can do this with nested loops, but it seems that there must be a simple way of extracting this matrix in one step with something like lapply, sapply, etc. I have seen similar problems answered throughout the web and this blog, but have not been able to correctly adapt them to this problem.  Another twist is some of the entries in results are 'Null', which happens when there is insufficient data for a specific company at a specific time to run the regression.

Any help or direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Since you are new here, you might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) sections of the website to help you get the most out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lapply` and `do.call`:

First create some sample data:

```
results <- list()
for (i in 1:5){
  results[[i]] <- list()
  for (t in 1:3){
    x <- sample(10)
    y <- sample(10)
    results[[i]][[t]] <- summary(lm(x~y))
  }
}
```

Then create the new matrix with the sigmas:

```
sigma <- do.call(rbind, lapply(results, function(x)lapply(x, function(y)y$sigma)))
colnames(sigma) <- paste("t", 1:ncol(sigma), sep="")
rownames(sigma) <- paste("c", 1:nrow(sigma), sep="")
```

the matrix looks as follows:

```
> sigma
   t1       t2       t3      
c1 2.302831 3.201325 3.154122
c2 3.066436 3.179956 3.146427
c3 2.752409 3.189946 2.819306
c4 3.211249 3.210777 2.983795
c5 3.179956 3.179956 2.340034
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm and was very fast.  I think I finally get the lapply syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Or another way:

```
sigma <- apply(simplify2array(results),1:2,function(v)v[[1]]$sigma)
```

Comment: Thanks much for the solution! I was not familiar with the simplify2array command. I also appreciate how quickly people responded.

Answer (score 0):

And another couple of ways, why not...

```
## seed used to generate data
set.seed(1)
sigs <- unlist(results)
sigma <- sigs[ names(sigs) %in% "sigma"]
sigma <- matrix(sigma , length( results ) )
#        [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
#[1,] 3.206527 2.797726 3.100342
#[2,] 3.208417 3.138230 3.138230
#[3,] 2.819306 3.138230 3.201325
#[4,] 3.179956 3.209833 3.194218
#[5,] 2.983795 2.652614 3.174233
```

Thanks to @user1981275 for providing some reproducible data.

Time is in columns.

A variation on `lapply` is to use `sapply` as it's return is already in the form you require:

```
t(sapply( results , function(x) sapply( x , function(y) y$sigma ) ) )
#        [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
#[1,] 3.206527 2.797726 3.100342
#[2,] 3.208417 3.138230 3.138230
#[3,] 2.819306 3.138230 3.201325
#[4,] 3.179956 3.209833 3.194218
#[5,] 2.983795 2.652614 3.174233
```

Comment: Thanks much!  Quick note, I found the second solution more robust than the first in that it carried the 'Null' entries to the matrix properly.  The first approach doesn't handle the 'Null' entries the same way and seems to drop them, which mis-aligned the results relative to the original (i,t) indices.